# c# Populating a combobox from datagridview with conditions

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

In my project I'm using a database like this

```
ID | Name   | Function
1  | John   | CH
2  | Maria  | CD
3  | Nikita | CH
4  | Carin  | CH
```

I'm using this piece of code to populate the combobox with all the names:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Person");
dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Function", typeof(string));

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
    dt.Rows.Add(MyComboBox.Items.Add(dataGridView[2, i].Value.ToString()
```

Now I'd like to populate the combobox with only some names, with a formula like this:

**for each name with CH Function
 - > add that name in MyCombobox**

I'm stuck with that, could you help me?

Comment: Please describe it more or give some more code

Comment: How are you databinding the datagridview? It would seem easier to use that same data and just filter it and then databind the combobox. Or better yet, do another query to the database with the function-column as where-clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***Try this***

```
MyComboBox.Items.Clear();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
{
    if (row.Cells["Function"].Value!=null && row.Cells["Function"].Value.Equals("CH"))
    MyComboBox.Items.Add(row.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: tel me if it works otherwise give some more code on the question. i give you answer as i understand your code.

Comment: Perfect, it's what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's do it right!

The `DataTable` is designed for data **storage**.
`DataGridView` and `ComboBox` are designed for data **represent**.

Puts data in `DataTable`

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Person");

dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Function", typeof(string));

dt.Rows.Add("1", "John", "CH");
dt.Rows.Add("2", "Maria", "CD");
dt.Rows.Add("3", "Nikita", "CH");
dt.Rows.Add("4", "Carin", "CH");
```

Bind raw data to `DataGridView`

```
dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
```

Now we need to bind filtered data to the `ComboBox`

```
DataView view = dt.AsDataView();
view.RowFilter = "Function = 'CH'";
comboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBox.DataSource = view;
```

Ready!

Now, if you change data in the `DataGridView`, those changes will automatically display in the `ComboBox`.

For example, change the `Function` column value from `CH` to `CD` for `John`, and he disappears from the `ComboBox`.

Also, you can dynamically change the filter conditions.

Specify

```
view.RowFilter = "Function = 'CD'";
```

Voila! The `ComboBox` now shows other names.

Comment: Elegant use of a dataview to get a filtered subset of a datatable :-)